# Limits and Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

There are three questions in total I am lost in. It comes from my homework.

1. If $x_n$ is a sequence such that $\lvert x_{k+1}-x_{k}\rvert<\frac{1}{2^k}$ for $k=1,2,3,...$, then show that $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.
2. Given $x_n\neq-1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. If  $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} x_n=0$, then show that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{x_n}{1+x_n}=0$ by checking the definition of limit.

My progress so far:

1. I am totally lost on this one.
2. I am aware that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} x_n=0 \Leftrightarrow \lvert x_n-0\rvert<\epsilon$, but I do not know how to integrate this into the proof.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $2)$ and $3)$ are classical and it is okay to put them together in one question. But $1)$ needs to be put alone in a new question.

Comment: Thanks! I have posted a new question with $1)$ alone.

Answer (score 0):

For #1, I'm pretty sure that $$x_n=2\sqrt{\frac{1-(-3/4)^n}{7}}$$ and hence $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n=2/\sqrt{7}.$$

Comment: Maybe you should put this answer to the new question of the OP (see comments in OP).

Comment: @par how did you get this explicit form?

Comment: @Jacky: I guess someone already answered in your new question. Main idea: square both sides, and then you have a linear recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

1. Note that for $n>m$, $$|x_m-x_n|=|x_m-x_{m+1}+x_{m+1}-x_{m+2}+\ldots+x_{n-1}-x_n|$$
2. Note that $$\frac{x_n}{1+x_n}=\frac{x_n+1-1}{1+x_n}=1-\frac{1}{1+x_n}$$

Comment: For 3, what do I do next?
$|1-\frac{1}{1+x_n}|<\epsilon \\ 1-\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}<x_n<1-\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}$
How do I use the fact $|x_n|<\epsilon$?

Comment: Well since $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=0$, you have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+x_n}=1$. More precisely, $x_n\to 0$ implies $y_n=1+x_n\to 1$ and $0\neq y_n\to 1$ implies $z_n=1/y_n\to 1$ (you can show it easily by contradiction). Finally $z_n\to 1$ implies $u_n=1-z_n\to 0$.

Comment: But I am required to use the definition of limit :(

Comment: @Jacky Well, this is a homework question and I will not do it for you. But I sparsed the demonstration for you. First show (with the definition) that $y_n\to 1$, e.g. by noticing that $|1-y_n|=|1-(1+x_n)|=|x_n|<\epsilon$ for some  $n$ big enough. Then for $z_n$ use contradiction (suppose there exists $\tilde\epsilon>0$ such that there exists $n>N$ with $|1-z_n|>\tilde{\epsilon}$ for every $N\in \Bbb N$). Etc... Is it more clear to you know?

Comment: sure! thanks for the insights